# Is there a mechanism for preventing a script from updating a google sheet whenever the sheet is modified or opened?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, static

I'm currently using this script

```
function TIMESTAMP() {

  var today = new Date();
  var date = (today.getMonth()+1)+'-'+today.getDate()+'-'+today.getFullYear();
  var time = today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes() + ":" + today.getSeconds();
  var dateTime = date+' '+time;
  return dateTime;

}
```

And I'm pairing it with a simple if statement `(If(A2=0, " ", TIMESTAMP())`

Every time I open the sheet, the cells update with the time I opened the sheet. I don't want that to happen - that is just a roundabout way of using the `Now()` function. What I want is a script that runs only once, when rows under `A` are auto-updated with an `importrange` function.

There are no other triggers on the script itself. How would I make the script produce static results?

Answer (score 0):

If you are making use of `IMPORTRANGE`, you will have to take into consideration the fact that this function recalculates every 30 minutes.

> Functions that pull data from outside the spreadsheet recalculate at the following times:
>
> `ImportRange`: 30 minutes

A solution to this would be to not use the `IMPORTRANGE` function and make use of Apps Script in order to import the data.

#### Reference

- [Set a spreadsheet’s location & calculation settings](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/58515?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en#zippy=%2Cchoose-how-often-formulas-calculate).